# Best traditional IRA investment for working person over 70?

Tags: investing, ira

My mother is 71 years old and plans to work at least 3 more years. She only recently opened a money market account (5%) and a traditional IRA. She put the maximum contribution for 2023---$7300---into the IRA. Now she needs to invest the IRA. I think she should be investing conservatively---she doesn't have enough money to suffer any losses. Her income is about $40,000 a year including social security. Net worth is about $315,000 but most of that is tied up in her house. What is the safest investment for her IRA, with a decent return?

Comment: *What is the safest investment for her IRA, with a decent return* - you can't get return without risk. You already mentioned money market - that's more or less the safest. you can get.

Comment: And yes, you can have a money market account within an IRA.

Comment: So could the IRA be invested in the same money market account that she already has? And is 5% the best she can do given her risk aversion?

Comment: Money markets paying 5% is historically unusual and caused by Fed hikes to fight inflation. Once they start easing, which consensus predicts in a few months, MM yields will decline, and more than a year out you (and she) shouldn't expect significantly more than inflation, probably 2-2.5%. Basically it will preserve your real capital, and defer taxes.

Comment: Note that missing out on returns, and thus losing ground to inflation, is also a kind of risk. This is really the "how do I decide how to invest/save at age X,  assuming lifespan of Y and expected/likely expenses A, B, and C, given my particular risk tolerance" question, and unless you are willing to do a lot of estimating/modelling work yourself the best answer may be to hire a fiduciary financial advisor to integrate those factors and recommend a mix that meets your goals.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments so far. They are very helpful.